# В заданной корректной позиции игры в шашки определить допустимость хода белых

Tags: c, массивы, математика

Сама задача: 
**В заданной корректной позиции игры в шашки определить допустимость хода белых**

Извиняюсь за повторение(первый вопрос я удалил). Посидел, подумал пару часов и решил проблему с первого вопроса.
Теперь программа выводит доску, на которой видны элементы.
Осталось определить допустимость хода белых. Мне кажется, нужно просто проверить с помощью if'a и все. Но при запуске VS сразу выдает критическую ошибку.
Помогите пожалуйста найти эту ошибку.

Код:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <time.h> 
#include <locale.h>
// 1 белая шашка, 0 пустое поле, 1 черная шашка
int acceptability(int *x[])
{
for (int i = 1; i<8; i++)
{
    for (int j = 1; j<8; j++)
    {
        if (x[i][j] == 1 && x[i + 1][j - 1] == 0 | x[i + 1][j + 1] == 0)                            
return 1;  // белые сверху
        else return 2;
    }
}
}
int main() {
setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "Russian");
int i = 0, j = 0;
int desk[8][8] = { 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0,
    0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,0,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,2,0,2,0,2,0,2,0 };
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) 
    printf("%d ", i + 1);
    printf("x y \n \n");
for (i = 0; i<8; i++) 
{
    for (j = 0; j<8; j++) 
    {
        printf("%d ", desk[i][j]);
    }
    printf("  %d \n", i + 1);
}
acceptability(desk);
if (acceptability(desk) == 1) printf(" Ход допустим ");
else printf(" Ошибка ");
_getch();
return 0;
}
```

P.S. Да, я не учел дамки и варианты со взятием в if'e, но это легко исправляется.

Comment: Н-да, с битовой арифметикой всё плохо. Q.E.D.

Comment: Тут не нужно добавлять "[Решено]" в заголовок. Сайт выделяет вопросы с принятым ответом с помощью оформления, и в параметрах поиска тоже есть `hasaccepted:yes`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`int acceptability(int *x[])` следует исправить на

```
int acceptability(int x[][8])
```

*Логику* вашей программы я просто не смотрю. Замечу только просто бросающееся в глаза.

Вот тут

```
if (x[i][j] == 1 && x[i + 1][j - 1] == 0 | x[i + 1][j + 1] == 0)
```

явно нужно логическое ИЛИ (`||`)

Там же - у вас `j` до 7 включительно. И что такое при `j==7` обращение `x[i + 1][j + 1]`? к какому элементу?

Непонятно, зачем тут

```
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
```

вводится новая переменная `i`, при объявленной с тем же именем выше.

Еще раз - *логику* я не проверял.

Comment: Да, сорян, совсем глупые ошибки, засиделся чет) На счет `if (x[i][j] == 1 && x[i + 1][j - 1] == 0 || x[i + 1][j + 1] == 0)` это просто проверка на пустоту клеток слева и справа от шашки ,что бы узнать, можно туда идти или нет.

Comment: Спасибо, отметил ответ принятым. Можно закрывать ;)